# Max from each of several dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have separate dataframes (file1, file2, file3 etc.), each containing the same data, with each dataframe representing a different day.

How would I find the max value in each dataframe, i.e. the equivalent of `max(file1$col1)`,  for all dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sapply(ls(pattern="file*"),
       function(myfile){
         max(get(myfile)$col1)})
```

Comment: I don't think you want quotes in the `get("myfile")` should be just `get(myfile)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
data.frames <- paste0("file", 1:3)
sapply(data.frames, function(x) max(get(x)$col1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad way to store data, but this could work

```
sapply(mget(c("file1","file2","file3")), function(x) max(x$col1))
```

You have to use `mget` in this case to round up your data.frames.

It would be better to store them in a list from the start.